# Ошибка при парсинге и выводе информации

Tags: java, android, jsoup

Хочу сделать так, чтобы с сайта, из блока `info`, парсило статьи, и была возможность вывода каждой статьи по отдельности, то есть, на сайте в блоке `info` есть 5 статей, а мне нужно вывести только 3.

Вот код моего приложения, при запуске сразу вылетает из приложения.

```
public class IndexActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

String popTovar;
String name;
String allPopTov;
final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); // Создаем массив строк
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.popular_tov);


    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("http://m.21vek.by").get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Elements popTovAll = doc.select("div.info");

                for (Element temp : popTovAll) {
                    list.add(popTovAll.text()); // Добавляем поочередно каждый элемент в массив
                }

        }
    }).start();


    /*Вызываем любую статью по ее порядковому номеру*/
    System.out.println(list.get(0));
    System.out.println(list.get(2));
    System.out.println(list.get(1));




}

}
```

Скриншот LogCat[image: LogCat]

Буду благодарен за помощь в решении проблемы!

Comment: А вы не задумывались о том, что забираете данные из коллекции раньше чем кладете их туда?

Comment: @SorryForMyEnglish Извините, можете указать как мне нужно сделать правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Само проще это сделать так.
Делаете в `IndexActivity` метод

```
private void print(){
  System.out.println(list.get(0));
  System.out.println(list.get(2));
  System.out.println(list.get(1));
}
```

В потоке после парсинга вызываете его

```
for (Element temp : popTovAll) {
        list.add(popTovAll.text()); // Добавляем поочередно каждый элемент в массив
}
print()
```

Comment: Получаю ошибку: 09-03 14:17:12.176: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-10
 09-03 14:17:12.176: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557): java.lang.NullPointerException
 09-03 14:17:12.176: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at vek.by.onlinesupermarket.IndexActivity$1.run(IndexActivity.java:37)
 09-03 14:17:12.176: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(557):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)

Comment: сделал так  for (int i = 0; i < popTovAll.size(); i++) {
      Element temp = popTovAll.get(i);
      list.add(popTovAll.text()); // Добавляем поочередно каждый элемент в массив
     } + ваш код и работает - спасибо сам